# Mockito can't verify subMethod call

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I am a bit new in testing, so bear with me.

I would like to test the behavior of onDismiss() method of mine. I would like to make sure that onDismiss() calls the showDialog() method for sure. In order to do this, I would like to verify is the mock in showDialog() being called or not. 
I am getting an error message, saying there is no interaction with that mock. If I run it with deBug mode, I see we step on the loadingDialog.show() line, still I am getting this error.

Questions:

- I would like to know, how can I test a subMethod call in this case?
- Why is this happening?

(showDialog() is already covered by separate tests)

**test**:

```
      sut.onDismiss(mockDialog)
      verify(mockLoadingDialog, times(1)).show();
```

**code**:

```
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
          showDialog();
    }


    public synchronized void showDialog() {     
          loadingDialog.show();
    }
```

Error message: `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Comment: How do you inject the mocks? Your mock `mockLoadingDialog` still has to be the same as the `loadingDialog` object, just a mocked version, otherwise how will it know the interactions?

Comment: I am using the @Mock annotation to create the mock object and passing them into the class through constructor dependency injection

Comment: I assume that you inject using `@InjectMocks` on the `sut` object for the constructor injection?

Answer (score 2):

```
package junit;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BasicTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Basic basic;

    @Mock
    private LoadingDialog mockLoadingDialog;

    @Mock
    private DialogInterface dialog;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnDismiss() {
        basic.onDismiss(dialog);
        verify(mockLoadingDialog, times(1)).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Using @InjectMocks ensures that the mocks are injected wherever necessary and you do not have to init mocks in setup.